# Merge multiple objects under a single object and add sibling object in one command

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

So I have three files:

##### cats.json

```json
{
  "cats": [
    {
      "name": "fluffles",
      "age": 10,
      "color": "white"
    }
  ]
}
```

##### dogs.json

```json
{
  "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": 5,
      "color": "black and white"
    },
    {
      "name": "rover",
      "age": 2,
      "color": "brown and white"
    }
  ]
}
```

##### snakes.json

```json
{
  "snakes": [
    {
      "name": "noodles",
      "age": 10,
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted to merge these together, under an "animals" object. I've found that will merge the files:

```
jq -s '{"animals": .} ' cats.json dogs.json snakes.json > animals.json
```

```json
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "cats": [
        {
          "name": "fluffles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dogs": [
        {
          "name": "sam",
          "age": 5,
          "color": "black and white"
        },
        {
          "name": "rover",
          "age": 2,
          "color": "brown and white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "snakes": [
        {
          "name": "noodles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "green"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have an additional object:

##### owners.json

```json
{
  "owners": [
    "peter",
    "william",
    "sally"
  ]
}
```

which I want to merge into the same file using

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' animals.json owners.json
```

Can I do both of these operations with just one `jq` command?

```
jq -s '{"animals": .} ' cats.json dogs.json snakes.json > animals.json
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]' animals.json owners.json
```

The result would look like this:

```json
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "cats": [
        {
          "name": "fluffles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dogs": [
        {
          "name": "sam",
          "age": 5,
          "color": "black and white"
        },
        {
          "name": "rover",
          "age": 2,
          "color": "brown and white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "snakes": [
        {
          "name": "noodles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "green"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "owners": [
    "peter",
    "william",
    "sally"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had an (a priori) indeterminate or large numbers of types of animals, and just one `owners` file.  In such cases, it would be better (to save memory) not to use the `-s` option, and it would be easier to invoke jq with the owners file as the first data file, e.g. along the lines of:

```
jq -n -f program.jq owners.json $(ls *.json | grep -v owners.json)
```

where program.jq contains a program such as:

```
input as $owners | {$owners, animals: [inputs]}
```

(Notice how `{"owners": $owners}` can be abbreviated.)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't actually think of the `-f` option. I think as this is the optimized answer I'll mark it as accepted. In my usecase I very much happen to have an _n_ number of animals.

Comment: As a follow up question to this. Is it possible to specify multiple inputs such as `owners.json`?

Comment: Yes, you might wish to consider using the --argfile option more than once, for example. Which option is best really depends on the details.

Comment: In this case, it's exactly the same as the owners object.

Comment: If I had a `{"food":["meat","fish","vegetables"]}` object and I wanted to append it, how would I modify the `program.jq`? Would the execution be `jq -n -f program.jq owners.json food.json $(ls *.json | grep -v 'owners.json|food.json')`?

Comment: Is the correct way to have two `program.jq` files? or can i do it in the same one. For example I tried `input as $owners, $food| {$owners, $food animals: [inputs]}` but was unable to get that to work.

Comment: As I said, it looks like you'll find using the --argfile command-line option convenient, though you might prefer --slurpfile.  If you cannot figure it out from the manual, I'd suggest opening another SO Q.

Comment: I took your advice and did that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69555673/joining-multiple-objects-under-a-single-object-and-adding-sibling-objects-using I'm starting to thing that a program.jq cannot take two "input as" instructions.

Comment: `input` and `inputs` can only read from one source. That's why I've emphasized the use of --argfile/--slurpfile, though there are other approaches too.

Comment: Thanks for that. and yes, that now makes sense. I simplified it by moving the slurped files to a different location to the other .json files, this means I don't need the grep option anymore, and they aren't read in twice. Eg: `jq -n -f program.jq --slurpfile owners /slurp/owners.json --slurpfile food /slurp/food.json /animals/*.json` with a jqprogram: `{$owners, food: $food[0].food, animals: [inputs]}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the way-to-go, but it gets the desired output by:

- Using `--slurp`:
- Catching the first 3 files as a single array variable
  `[ .[0] * .[1] * .[2] ] as $all`
- Catching `owners` object as a single variable
  `.[3].owners as $owners`
- Creating the object as desired
  `{ "animals": $all, "owners": $owners }`

```
jq \
    --slurp \
    '[ .[0] * .[1] * .[2] ] as $all | .[3].owners as $owners | { "animals": $all, "owners": $owners }' cats.json dogs.json snakes.json owners.json
```

Will produce:

```json
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "cats": [
        {
          "name": "fluffles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "white"
        }
      ],
      "dogs": [
        {
          "name": "sam",
          "age": 5,
          "color": "black and white"
        },
        {
          "name": "rover",
          "age": 2,
          "color": "brown and white"
        }
      ],
      "snakes": [
        {
          "name": "noodles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "green"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "owners": [
    "peter",
    "william",
    "sally"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I even found a way to make it work with any number of animals: `jq -s '[ .[0] * .[1] * .[2] ] as $all | .[3].owners as $owners | { "animals": $all, "owners": $owners }' *.json ~/owners.json` so i think this is probably the right answer.

Comment: Ahh nice, sound great! But won't the first `*.json` also include the `owners` file? Hope that doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Would have to store it in a different place. See above answer is an alternative solution that does solve that though, and is more optimized.