# Joining multiple objects under a single object and adding sibling objects using jq -f .jq

Tags: json, shell, command-line, jq

So from what I gather `jq` [does support](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/461) using `-f` multiple times. However I'm not sure if this is what I want.

So I have:

### cats.json

```json
{
  "cats": [
    {
      "name": "fluffles",
      "age": 10,
      "color": "white"
    }
  ]
}
```

### dogs.json

```json
{
  "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "sam",
      "age": 5,
      "color": "black and white"
    },
    {
      "name": "rover",
      "age": 2,
      "color": "brown and white"
    }
  ]
}
```

### snakes.json

```json
{
  "snakes": [
    {
      "name": "noodles",
      "age": 10,
      "color": "green"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was able to merge this object:

### owners.json

```json
{
  "owners": [
    "peter",
    "william",
    "sally"
  ]
}
```

using

```
jq -n -f program.jq owners.json $(ls *.json | grep -v 'owners.json')
```

which contains the `jq` program

```
input as $owners | {$owners, animals: [inputs]}
```

as suggested [in the reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69183207/16742581).

However I'm not sure what to do if I want to merge two additional objects, say I had:

### food.json

```json
{
  "food": [
    "meat",
    "fish",
    "vegetables"
  ]
}
```

as well that I want at the top, resulting in:

```json
{
  "owners": [
    "peter",
    "william",
    "sally"
  ],
  "food": [
    "meat",
    "fish",
    "vegetables"
  ],
  "animals": [
    {
      "cats": [
        {
          "name": "fluffles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dogs": [
        {
          "name": "sam",
          "age": 5,
          "color": "black and white"
        },
        {
          "name": "rover",
          "age": 2,
          "color": "brown and white"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "snakes": [
        {
          "name": "noodles",
          "age": 10,
          "color": "green"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ls | grep`? It's [generally an antipattern](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and I'm hard-pressed to see the value here (if you want to expand `*owners.json*` on the command line to list files that have that as a substring, you can do that without `ls`).

Comment: Neither jq nor gojq supports multiple `-f FILE` options, except in the sense that all but the first such specification is ignored. You misread the (closed) "issue" that you cited. Since multiple use of the -f option is indeed irrelevant to the question, to avoid confusion, I would suggest that you simply delete the first paragraph of your Q.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -What alternative to `ls *.jq | grep -v '^owners\.json$` would you propose?  (Note the -v option.)

Comment: @peak, with extglob enabled, `!(*owners.json*).jq`. But how could `*.jq` ever match `owners.json` in the first place?

Comment: without it none of the other files besides owners.json and food.json are read in.

Comment: @dogman, that makes it look like you just want `jq -f program.jq *.json`. No point to the `ls | grep` dance there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Of course I meant `ls *.json ....`. The point is that owners.json must occur first.  Using extglob is a bit of a hack, at best.

Comment: The reason for the `ls *.json | grep -v 'owners.json|food.json'` is to prevent them being added twice, when specifying *.json, they'd need to be stored in a different directory otherwise.

Comment: I simplified it by moving the slurped files to a different location to the other .json files, this means I don't need the grep option anymore, and they aren't read in twice. Eg: `jq -n -f program.jq --slurpfile owners /slurp/owners.json --slurpfile food /slurp/food.json /animals/*.json` with a jqprogram: `{$owners, food: $food[0].food, animals: [inputs]}`

Comment: @dogman, if you want to stop a glob from matching a specific filename, enable `extglob` support and then you can use `!(owners|food).json` to match all `.json` files except `owners.json` and `food.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read in `food.json` using parameter `--slurpfile food food.json` and modify `program.jq` to include it: `input as $owners | {$owners, food: $food[0].food, animals: [inputs]}`.

Comment: I can't get that to work. `input as $owners | {$owners, food: $food[0].food, animals: [inputs]}`, then with `jq -n -f program.jq owners.json -s food food.json` i get `jq: error: $food is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
input as $owners | {$owners, food: $food[0].food, animals: [inputs]}`

Comment: And with `jq -s '[ .[0] * .[1] * .[2] ] as $all | .[3].owners as $owners | .[4].food as $food | { "animals": $all, "owners": $owners, "food": $food }' *.json owners.json food.json` i get `"food": null`.

Comment: You used `-s` which is shorthand for `--slurp` not `--slurpfile` which I intended to use.

Comment: success: that does work: `jq -n -f program.jq owners.json --slurpfile food food.json  $(ls *.json | grep -v 'owners.json')` my bad about the -s. Do you know if jq programs can take inputs from more than one method?

Comment: You can have multiple (data) input files and apparently you make use of them (`ls *.json`), but to my knowledge you can't have more than one program (code) input, be it as inline parameter or referenced using `-f`. You could, however, alter what parameter `-f` is reading using, for instance,  process substitution `-f <(cat program1.jq; echo "|"; cat program2.jq)`. However, I'd discourage you from applying such quirks as they can easily become confusing and error-prone.

Comment: i don't really want to have two program.jq files i want to know if i can use two inputs in the one program.jq, ie like how i did for owners.json

Comment: @dogman, using `--slurpfile` _does_ introduce another input to be run in the current program. I'm a little unclear what you're asking for that the answer doesn't already describe.

Comment: I guess I am a bit confused that I didn't need --slurpfile for owner.json, so i figured I could do that again somehow.

Comment: @dogman, ...if you _want to_ use `-n` to make the default input be empty and use `--slurpfile` for 100% of your inputs, you can do that.

Comment: as @peak [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69180158/merge-multiple-objects-under-a-single-object-and-add-sibling-object-in-one-comma/69183207#comment122944606_69183207) `input` and `inputs` can only read from one source. So that answers that.